# alfresco javascript inheritance and paths

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I am writing a simple script on javascript for Alfresco Community. I have the script runnign everytime a new file is uploaded.

I need to check wether an specific filename (label.txt) exists in the folder. If it exists, I will use the information contained in the file for later treatment.

If I set the filename alone it works as long as the folder itself is the one with the script asigned, it works perfecly.

```
var labelFile = space.childByNamePath("label.txt");
   if (labelFile != null)
   {
   ...
   }
```

When i set the inheritance of the script to lower level folders the script runs but still tries to find the `label.txt` file in the root folder. I am trying to locate the actual path of the uploaded document:

```
var dpath = document.displayPath  + "/label.txt";
var labelFile = space.childByNamePath(dpath);
logFile.content += "labelFile: " + labelFile.displayPath + "\r\n";
   if (labelFile != null)
   {
   ...
   }
```

I am getting a supposedly correct path in the dpath var, but I get a NULL result on the file object so I cannot read the file and its content.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not about inheritance, but space.childByNamePath just accepting relative paths, not absolute, so I ahd to calculate it from the space root:

```
var dpath = document.displayPath;
var dpatharray = dpath.split("/");
var dpathlength = dpatharray.length;
var spath = space.displayPath;
var spatharray = spath.split("/");
var spathlength = spatharray.length;
var labelpath = "";
for (var i=spathlength + 1; i<dpathlength; i++)
{
    labelpath += dpatharray[i] + "/";
}

var labelFile = space.childByNamePath(labelpath + "label.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

What is "space" there? Try using "companyhome", see this for further ideas. http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/references/API-JS-rootscoped.html

> The current space ScriptNode (if any). For a script executing from a
>   rule,  the space object is the space in which the rule resides. If the rule is inherited, this may not be the expected space.

Comment: I read that and that is exactly the problem I am having. I expect the users to upload their files in new folders under the importing folder (the one with the script) and add inormation in a known file "label.txt". As I cannot lay on space path i need to capture the document path (the real route where they are uploading data). But this is not working.

Comment: It's not working since you're applying the rule to children spaces, and the "space" root object is different every time. Root object "companyhome" on the other hand should always be the same.

Comment: I think that my problem, as I am testing it now, has more to see with "childByNamePath()" not accepting the absolute path that "displayPath" returns. I have to try some string editing to get a working solution.